# How to add fields in existing class in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

Please i want to add some fields in an existing class in odoo which is 'product_template'.
Here is my code:

```
class product_template(models.Model):
    #Inhertis the model product.template
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    _name = 'product.template'
    _columns =  {
'CostPrice' : fields.float('Buy price'),
'ShippingCost' : fields.float('Shipping Cost'),
'FieldAfterGroup' : fields.char(string='Field After Group'),
'FieldNewPage' : fields.char(string='Field New Page'),

   }
```

And the xml:

```
<record id="view_product_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template.common.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
            <xpath expr="//page[@string='Information']" position="after">
        <page name="Sample" string="Custom page">
      <group>
            <field name="FieldNewPage"/>
     </group>
         </page>
    </xpath>


    <xpath expr="//page[@string='Information']/group" position="after">
        <group>
         <field name="FieldAfterGroup"/>
        </group>
    </xpath>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_form_inherit_tree">
    <field name="name">product.template.common.form.inherit.tree</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Services" >
             <field name="FieldNewPage"/>
     <field name="FieldAfterGroup"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>


<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_product">
    <field name="name">product.template</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
```

But i got this error:
     'module' object has no attribute 'integer'

Can anyone help me please or explain to me how to modify existing fields in odoo please.

Comment: You shouldn't mention the attribute `_name` when you want to extend an existing table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i deleted it abd it doesnt work.

Comment: Please can you tell what i should put in the menuitem in the xml file please

Answer (score 0):

You have used `models.Model` in that you have to use the pattern as Odoo-8.
Just replace `models.Model` with `osv.osv`.

```
class product_template(osv.osv):
    #Inhertis the model product.template
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    _name = 'product.template'
    _columns =  {
'CostPrice' : fields.float('Buy price'),
'ShippingCost' : fields.float('Shipping Cost'),
'FieldAfterGroup' : fields.char(string='Field After Group'),
'FieldNewPage' : fields.char(string='Field New Page'),

   }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the issue now you face after changes I suggest ? and please remove _name attribute as well. Yes you can put menuitems in xml. You need to restart odoo service after changes the py files. or need to update module after changes in xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This Code For odoo 8

```
class product_template(models.Model):
    #Inhertis the model product.template
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    _name = 'product.template'

    CostPrice = fields.Float('Buy price')
    ShippingCost = fields.Float('Shipping Cost')
    FieldAfterGroup = fields.Char(string='Field After Group')
    FieldNewPage = fields.Char(string='Field New Page')
```